# Why is my function being called infinitely? (react-native/expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a video playlist, and when each video ends I would like to play the next video. So far I figured out how to play the next video but then the method this.playnext() is called infinitely, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code, this.playnext() is being called infinitely when the video ends. Any idea on how to fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Video } from 'expo';
let styles = require('../stylesheet.js');


export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playlist: [
        {src:require('../assets/videos/asthma-1.mp4'),name:'asthma-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/asthma-2.mp4'),name:'asthma-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/asthma-3.mp4'),name:'asthma-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/copd-1.mp4'),name:'copd-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/copd-2.mp4'),name:'copd-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/copd-3.mp4'),name:'copd-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/diabetes-1.mp4'),name:'diabetes-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/diabetes-2.mp4'),name:'diabetes-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/diabetes-3.mp4'),name:'diabetes-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/emphysema-1.mp4'),name:'emphysema-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/emphysema-2.mp4'),name:'emphysema-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/emphysema-3.mp4'),name:'emphysema-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hyperlipidemia-1.mp4'),name:'hyperlipidemia-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hyperlipidemia-2.mp4'),name:'hyperlipidemia-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hyperlipidemia-3.mp4'),name:'hyperlipidemia-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hypertension-1.mp4'),name:'hypertension-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hypertension-2.mp4'),name:'hypertension-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/hypertension-3.mp4'),name:'hypertension-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/narcolepsy-1.mp4'),name:'narcolepsy-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/narcolepsy-2.mp4'),name:'narcolepsy-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/narcolepsy-3.mp4'),name:'narcolepsy-3'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/pneumonia-1.mp4'),name:'pneumonia-1'}, 
        {src:require('../assets/videos/pneumonia-2.mp4'),name:'pneumonia-2'},
        {src:require('../assets/videos/pneumonia-3.mp4'),name:'pneumonia-3'}
      ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    alert('turnip')
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nP){
      let newvideo = nP.video;
      let playlist = this.state.playlist;
      let nextsrc;
      let indexofnewvid;
      for(let i = 0; i <= playlist.length - 1; i++){
        if(playlist[i].name.includes(newvideo)){
          nextsrc = playlist[i];
          indexofnewvid = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      for(let i = 0; i <= indexofnewvid - 1; i++){
        let temp = playlist[0];
        playlist.shift();
        playlist.push(temp);
      }
      this.setState({playlist,})
  }
  componentWillUpdate(prevState, nextState){
    console.log(nextState);
  }
  callern(playbackStatus){
    if(playbackStatus['didJustFinish']){
      console.log('ended');
      this.playnext();
    }else{
      console.log('playing paused or loading');
    }
  }
  playnext(){
    console.log("playing next");
    let playlist = this.state.playlist;
    let temp = playlist[0];
    playlist.shift();
    playlist.push(temp);
    this.setState({playlist,})
  }
  render(){
    return(
     <Video

      onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(playbackStatus)=> this.callern(playbackStatus)}
      source={this.state.playlist[0].src}
      posterSource={require('../assets/images/Signal_Logo.png')}
      rate={1.0}
      volume={1.0}
      muted={false}
      useNativeControls
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={styles.player} />
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*[The documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av.html#playbackobjectsetonplaybackstatusupdateonplaybackstatusupdate)* says

> `onPlaybackStatusUpdate` will be called whenever a call to the API for this `playbackObject` completes ..... and will also be called at regular intervals while the media is in the loaded state.

*[You probably want to take advantage of `didJustFinish`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av.html#didjustfinish--a-boolean-describing-if-the-media-just-played-to-completion-at-the-time-that-this-status-was-received-when-the-media-plays-to-completion-the-function-passed-in-setonplaybackstatusupdate-is-called-exactly-once-with-didjustfinish-set-to-true-didjustfinish-is-never-true-in-any-other-case)*.

> a boolean describing if the media just played to completion at the time that this status was received. When the media plays to completion, the function passed in `setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate()` is called exactly once with `didJustFinish` set to true. `didJustFinish` is never `true` in any other case.

Comment: Hi, if you'll refer to my code, you'll note that I have used didJustFinish in callern() method. I'm having some trouble understanding how to use setOnPlayblackStatusUpdate(). Specifically the line "playbackObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate();" confuses me. I'm not quite sure  how to get a handle on playbackObject as the example shows 'const playbackObject = new Expo.Audio.Sound();' and I used <Video> tag. Can you clarify with some code for my use case?